# Forwarding tcp request to remote api in Nodejs, Express

Tags: node.js, web-services, rest, tcp

i am using nodejs and express to build a restful webservice with no DB behind, but communicate with diffrent remote restful webservices, and i encountered the following problem,

My server located on US, but i have users from all around the world,

One of my remotes restful services that i am working with, does not support geo querying (not even by ip), and he asked me to do forwarding tcp request to his api, so he'll recogize users geo on his side.

I am using hyper-request as my module for sending request, but relavnet solution with any other module will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your other remote services to lookup the Geographic data of the IP you will need to proxy the requests with an extra [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP Header, and they will have to whitelist your server's IP as a trustworthy proxy.

But you cannot spoof your source IP so that it matches your original user's.

Comment: i am using aws ec2 and elb on multiplie regions, so my instances ips constantly changing

Comment: Your outgoing IP should not change constantly. And there is no other way other than setting an X-Forwarded-For, you cannot spoof your outgoing IP to use your original user's IP, the only solution then would be to have him directly use the service you're connecting to.

Comment: since i couldn't give the list of whitelist ips, is there any other way to find out which ip belongs the client's on the remote api side? say something like order of IPs

Comment: If you cannot whitelist the IPs then you will have to use a shared token or some kind of authentication to call that service and they will have to edit their specs so that you can give them the original IP somewhere in your call.

Comment: just tested it out, and i see that added X-Forwarded-For ip, always comes first, it's looks like : 'added new ip', 'server ip'